# How to write a * .kl file and copy to / system on a rooted system

Tags: android, xamarin.android, adb, root, kiosk-mode

I have the following problem.

I need to lock my tablet for a specific app. I am using my application in KioskMode, however I need to block some buttons, "Switch_app", "Volume_UP", "Volume_DOWN", etc.

I was able to block these buttons by accessing the ES File Explorer and changing the file manually, saving and restarting the tablet.

However, I would like to change this file progammatically.

I've tried the following:

```
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl"))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("VOLUME"))
                    {
                        line = $"# {line}";

                    }
                    text += line + "\n";
                    System.Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
            CreateFile();

            TransferFile();
        };


    void CreateFile()
    {


        string sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        string path = Path.Combine(sdCard, "MyFolder/Generic.kl");
        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);
        }
    }
```

And to transfer the created file to / system / usr / Keylayout I use this:

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mount -o rw,remount,rw /system");
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c rm system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mv /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/Generic.kl system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
```

When I use these commands, the file is copied, but when I restart the tablet no more physical buttons work. So I believe it's some problem related to deleting the old file and adding the new one.

Any help will be very welcome as well as ideas.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to worry about ownership, permissions, etc. if you would use `sed`'s in place editing:

```
GetRuntime().Exec("su 0 mount -o remount,rw /system");
GetRuntime().Exec("su 0 sed -i 's/^[^#]*VOLUME_DOWN/# &/' /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
GetRuntime().Exec("su 0 sed -i 's/^[^#]*VOLUME_UP/# &/' /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
GetRuntime().Exec("su 0 sed -i 's/^[^#]*APP_SWITCH/# &/' /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
```

You still need to reboot though.

Comment: Thanks Alex P.

You helped me a lot because I was facing permissions issues and now I do not have them anymore.

Can you get me a question? If I need to disable, how do I write the reverse?

Comment: Remove the Comment at VOLUME_DOWN - VOLUME_UP

Answer (score 1):

That's the solution Rooted devices

```
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mount -o rw,remount,rw /system");
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c rm system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mv /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/Generic.kl system/usr/keylayout/");
        **Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c chmod 644 /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c chown system.system /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");**
```